# Will your item return to the world in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft will the items in your inventory return to the world after Death? I was far away from home mining and I couldn't find my way back. So I killed myself to get back home.

My question is: **will the items return to my world or will they be destroyed permanently?**

By 'return into the world' I mean it can be in the same place they were when I found them, it doesn't necessarily have to be in the same shape they were when I died.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [relevant wiki source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Item_%28entity%29):

> Items despawn after 6000 game [ticks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tick) (5 minutes) of being in a loaded [chunk](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk), unless another item of the same kind was dropped next to them and added to its stack. Merging dropped item stacks will set the new stack's despawn time to the lower of the two times.

Comment: Thank you ^.^ so i don't have to restart the game then?

Comment: @SheenaRaquelMaroney No.

Comment: Thank you you have no idea how much this means to me lol. Newbie!

Comment: @SheenaRaquelMaroney If you found the answer nice, please consider clicking the check mark to accept it. Thank you!